# Design considerations for unattended product in public place

Tags: design

When designing a product that is to be installed and left unattended in a potentially publicly accessible place, what considerations are taken in order to minimise the risk of vandalism and theft? Some example problems:

- The risk of the device being opened and peripherals (such as SIM cards, SD cards etc) being stolen.
- General vandalism to the enclosure and any external connections (e.g. antennas, service ports etc).

It would be great to hear others challenges and experiences in this part of the electronic product design process.

Comment: This question is very broad. You might get better responses if you specify what type of device you wish to install.

Comment: Also, "public place" is really not very specific. The front fence of the white house is a public place, but good luck vandalizing anything there. Then, there's a lot of wars in this world, and making something safe against vandalism by someone who can carry high velocity ballistic weapons and use them without repercussions is maybe a bit different than making it safe agains the occasional city centre drunk.

Comment: Painting. Near me is a riverside path which the council kindly provided with boards that describe the local ecology and history, none of which can be read because they are covered in spray painted graffiti (or gang signs I think, not really an area of my expertise). Humans are territorial animals who love to leave their markings to demonstrate this territorial dominance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said.. there is no such thing as a people proof box.

Obviously the "harder" you make the enclosure the more you will slow them down, but you will just p-off somebody enough to get a bigger hammer.

Keeping it unobtrusive and high off the ground so folks walk by without ever seeing it helps, and a big sticker on the front that says "DANGER! LETHAL VOLTAGES INSIDE!" can also act as a deterrent.

If you don't want it back after, and plan to replace rather than service, you can always pot the thing up in thermally conductive electrically insulated epoxy, so it's just a big brick.

You can of course also add a siren that goes off if the thing is opened. But you will need someone local to shut it off.

Connectors can be in their own space inside the box only exiting as cables through clamps in U-Shaped cut-outs in the bottom of the box.

Ultimately though there is a cost balance. How much is what is in the box worth versus how much can you afford to pay to stop someone from stealing/destroying it.